# Can Mail fetch email signature set using Google Mail?

Tags: email, gmail, import

My organisation's people use a mixture of Apple Mail and Gmail.com as a client for our Gmail addresses. We use a GSuite app to set peoples' Gmail signatures, which works great for those sending email from Gmail.com, but the signature is not 'imported' by Apple Mail. This means people have to manually copy their Gmail signature into the Apple Mail signature preferences. Is there any way to remedy this?

I understand that this may not be a shortcoming of Apple Mail, but a shortcoming of Gmail.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using Outlook Desktop as it allows me to copy/paste the GSuite signature. 
With the Apple Mail is a pain to resize the images and you just cannot float them.

I opened a tread on Apple Community: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250552009 and I hope to receive a reply.

But I believe there is no easy way out. You cannot copy/paste or import signature from GSuite and you might need to edit everything.

Very silly.